# I want to separate numbers whose last digits is same

Tags: python, function, loops

I defined a function by:

```
input : two numbers l,k   
output: the number k in base l
```

**Code**

```
def base(k,l):
    result=''
    while k!=0:
        remainder = k%l
        k=k//l
        result= result + str(remainder)
    return result
n=3
t=10
for i in range(n**t):
    print(base(i,n).zfill(t))
```

The loop generates numbers in base n. Now I want to separate the numbers with same last digit.
**For ex:** If the loop gives output as `01,10,11` then it separates numbers `01 and 11`. I want to do the same for n same last digits. In other words, I want to separate the numbers with last digit `0,1,2` and so on

I can't store these values in an array as I want to have very large iterations.

Comment: Can you further explain what you would like to achieve as an output, what do you mean by separate numbers that ends with the same digit ? from your explanation above you wanted to separate 01 and 10 these 2 doesn't end with the same digit (assuming base 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a lazy version of this (using [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)) would be:

```
from itertools import product

base = 3
n_digits = 5

last_digits = list(range(base))  # [0, 1, 2]

remaining_digits = product(range(base), repeat=n_digits - 1)
for digits in remaining_digits:
    print(digits)

# (0, 0, 0, 0)
# (0, 0, 0, 1)
# (0, 0, 0, 2)
# ...
# (2, 2, 2, 0)
# (2, 2, 2, 1)
# (2, 2, 2, 2)
```

for any possible `last_digits` you get `remaining_digits` that you can prepend to them. the `remaining_digits` here is an iterator - it will not store all the elements in memory.

you can then combine `last_digits` and `remaining_digits` any way you want (e.g. combine them to a `str`ing or an `int`eger as needed).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
# Creating a blank map from 0-9 to empty arrays(to store numbers)
MAP = {str(i):[] for i in range(10)}

# Then populate the dictionary like so
for i in range(n**t):
    num = base(i,n).zfill(t)
    MAP[num[-1]].append(num)
```

**NOTE :** num[-1] will give the last digit of num.

Comment: Hey, i have some syntax python questions.

Comment: 1. what n**t mean?

Comment: 2. what is {str(i):[] - exactly : [] - do ?

Comment: 1) n**t means power, n to the power of t.
2) {str(i):[] for i in range(9)} is a python oneliner for intitalising a dictonary

Comment: Go through this link for more help on this : [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/comprehensions-in-python/)

Comment: @PiotrŻak n**t is n raised to power t

Comment: @MohammedAadil As I mentioned, I can't store values in array as my iterations are going to be very large

Comment: I dont think there is a faster way than this. What do you want to do with the data? How many elements are you going to be iterating over?

Comment: @MohammedAadil i'd think my way is faster (and certainly more memory efficient); there is no need for a `mod`ulo and `floordiv` operation (`divmod` should have been used anyway) - also the  conversion to `str`ing is not strictly necessary.

Comment: Hmm, just saw your answer @hiroprotagonist . Thats a really elegent way.